# intern functional tests using remote web driver are all failing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, intern

**Background:**

After getting my infrastructure properly setup to have intern run functional tests against a set of VMs.  All machines exist on the same network.

I am using intern to run my functional tests.

*not using sauce labs but rather selenium grid 2 - hub & nodes.

**Problem:**

All functional test cases are failing.

> Error: Student Name field should contain same string that was entered:
>   expected '' to equal 'qwerty' AssertionError: Student Name field
>   should contain same string that was entered: expected '' to equal
>   'qwerty'

**Observations:**

I see the form field getting filled out, but when I do the assert - something as simple as get the text and match it with expected input, I get the error response 7.

**What I've Tried**
Here is the typical boiler plate for a functional test case.

```
       studentName: function () {
             return this.remote
                 .get('http://some.ip.addr:3000/#students')
                 .elementById('name')
                .clickElement()
                .type('qwerty')
                 .end()
                 .elementById('name')
                 .text()
                 .then(function(resultText){
                    assert.equal(resultText, 'qwerty', 'Student Name field should contain same string that was entered');               
                  });
       }
```

**Other Notes:**
    [Link to Status Response Codes that are mentioned above](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#Response_Status_Codes)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the '' (empty string) being returned is to use:

```
.elementById('name')
    .getAttribute('value')
```

instead of

```
.elementById('name')
    text()
```

This was sent to me by a contact that works on the project.  Here is his explanation:

> Basically, .text() will not get the value of a form field, so you need
>   to use WebDriver's getAttribute()